# Problems traversing xml file with Java

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to traverse a simple XML document with Java, but for some reason whitespace is being counted as nodes.  For example, I have this:

```
        factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        DOMImplementation domImpl = builder.getDOMImplementation(); 
        factory.setIgnoringComments(true);
        factory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
        DOMImplementationLS ls = (DOMImplementationLS) domImpl.getFeature("LS", "3.0");
        LSInput in = ls.createLSInput();
        in.setByteStream(is);
        LSParser parser = ls.createLSParser(DOMImplementationLS.MODE_SYNCHRONOUS, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");

        document = parser.parse(in);
        document.getDocumentElement().getFirstChild()
```

So for the following XML, the first child returned is some combination of whitespace.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opendap>
<root url="http://localhost/" filter=".*" />
<rewrite>
    <var name="altitude" type="enum" resAttr="getNodeName" profattr="profattr"/>

</rewrite>
<constants>
    <catalogURL>http://google.com</catalogURL>
</constants>
<resAttr>
    <Publishers>person1</Publishers>
    <Publishers>person2</Publishers>
</resAttr>

</opendap>
```

How do I fix this?

Edit: I've kind of fixed it by doing this (resattr is Element representing ). Unfortunately, the setValidating didn't work.

```
    for (Node child = this.resAttr.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling()){

        if (child.getFirstChild() != null && child.getFirstChild().getNodeValue() != null){
            String nodename = child.getNodeName();
            String nodevalue = child.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
```

Comment: What version of Java and JAX-P are you using? There is a bug with that method http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6545684

Comment: // Compiled from DocumentBuilder.java (version 1.5 : 49.0, super bit)
public abstract class javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.  Also using java 1.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sackers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082527/problems-traversing-xml-file-with-java/4083051#4083051) is on the right track - the parser needs to be in validating mode. The document probably also needs a grammar (the parser documentation also mentions sections [2.10](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-white-space) and [3.2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-element-content) of the XML spec).

For example, configured with `setValidating(true)` and `setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true)`, the parser will strip the whitespace between the x and y elements, but not within the y element since this is PCDATA:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE x [
  <!ELEMENT x (y+)>
  <!ELEMENT y (#PCDATA)>
]>

<x>
  <y>  </y>
</x>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the docs for 'setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace' - 'Due to reliance on the content model this setting requires the parser to be in validating mode.'. Have you tried:

```
factory.setValidating(true);
```